# Why do 'rpm -qa' and 'yum list' display different result?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

I need to check if bzip2 package is installed in my RHEL7.6.

The result of the 1st commmand

```
rpm -qa | grep bzip2
```

was

```
bzip2-devel-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64
bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64
```

but the result of the 2nd command

```
yum list | grep bzip2
```

was

```
bzip2-devel.x86_64                      1.0.6-13.el7               installed
bzip2-libs.x86_64                       1.0.6-13.el7               @rhel
bzip2.x86_64                            1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
bzip2-devel.i686                        1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
bzip2-libs.i686                         1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
```

When I tried compressing a file using bzip2 -k command, it actually worked. So there exists bzip2.
Then why does 'rpm -qa' command not show bzip2?

Comment: By the way, the `bzip2` package installs a file named `bzip2` (not "bzip").

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks. I edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `yum list` shows **available packages**, while `rpm -qa` shows only those which were **installed**.

In your example

```
bzip2-devel.x86_64                      1.0.6-13.el7               installed
bzip2-libs.x86_64                       1.0.6-13.el7               @rhel
bzip2.x86_64                            1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
bzip2-devel.i686                        1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
bzip2-libs.i686                         1.0.6-13.el7               rhel
```

only the first two were installed (by different routes, according to the third column).

Comment: `yum list installed | grep bzip2` might be a good comparison.

Comment: @jsbillings The command you suggested tells me only 'bzip2-devel' and 'bzip2-libs' have been installed, but not 'bzip2'. Then why is 'bzip2' command working??

Comment: Check what the path to the `bzip2` command with `which bzip2`. Then check what package it belongs to with `rpm -qf /usr/bin/bzip2`. (assuming the `which` command said it was in /usr/bin)

Comment: @jsbillings It is in '/usr/local/bin/bzip2' Both of '/usr/bin/bzip2' and 'usr/local/bin/bzip2' are not owned by any package.

Comment: In the '/usr/bin/bzip2' folder, there are bin, include, lib, and man folders, but in the '/usr/local/bin' folder, there is no 'bzip2' folder but there are only two files: bzip2 and bzip2recover

Comment: ...but how bzip2 got there, probably no one can answer (except for the person who copied or compiled it).

Comment: You, or someone with super user on your system, has installed a bzip2 from source or some other method.  It is not a rhel package.